# Print csv to a path

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, zip

I have the following code:

How can I ask to move my output files to a path?

```
for i, j in groupby:
    csv = j.to_csv(index=False)
    with open("{}.csv".format(n), 'w') as out_file:
       out_file.write(csv)

zipsites.write("{}.csv".format(i))
zipsites.close()
```

Comment: Please fix your codes indentation

Comment: Isn't `n` already the path? If it's just the filename, append the path to the front of it.

Comment: with open("{}.csv".format(i), 'w') as out_file:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the details provided in the question and the example, I think all you need is to add
a `path` variable that is just appended to the CSV filename? Modifying your code,

```
path = 'DRIVE:\somefolder\someotherfolder\'

for i, j in groupby:
csv = j.to_csv(index=False)
with open("{}{}.csv".format(path, n), 'w') as out_file:
   out_file.write(csv)

zipsites.write("{}{}.csv".format(path, i))
zipsites.close()
```